# Things to see in Nova Scotia, that aren't Halifax centric

Tags: sightseeing, canada, nova-scotia

Looking to be in New Scotland in middle of September on business, and while I'm there, I'd like to see more of the province then what little I've seen so far (aka downtown Halifax). However, outside of Peggy's Cove, it seems the tourism planners seem to think Nova Scotia's appeal ends at Halifax's city limits.

So I bring it to you, does anyone have any recommendations of what to see, what to do, and where to go in Nova Scotia?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Lunenburg](http://www.explorelunenburg.ca/) is a UNESCO world heritage site. Tourists go there from all over. You could also walk the [Cabot Trail](http://www.cabottrail.com/) (not that Cape Breton is super close to Halifax, but if you're outdoorsy you'll love it) or go see the tides in the [Bay of Fundy](http://bayoffundytourism.com/). The [provincial tourism board](http://www.novascotia.com/en/home/default.aspx) is not a bad place to start for details and more ideas.

Comment: If you are based in the non-Atlantic part of Canada, you may be surprised how fast it is to get around Nova Scotia. Lunenburg is only a few hours away.

Comment: Everything is relative. I would not consider Cape Breton super close to Halifax, it's a 4-hour drive away, not really close enough for a day trip. But relatively to whole Canada, it is close enough to take a few days to go there. Also, to add to the post, I would say that from Lunenburg, taking the 332 westbound is a very scenic road.

Answer (score 8):

I'd check out the coast as much as possible.  I drove in from New Brunswick, such a beautiful ride.  There are a lot of little islands with strong French heritage and stuff.  Try to see as much as possible.  One of my favorite places, really.  If you're a golfer, there are some great courses out there as well.

Answer (score 6):

If you are a geek (and what are you doing on this site if not?) try the Alexander Graham Bell Museum in Baddeck. In his spare time after inventing the telephone, Bell organized the first powered flight in the British Empire right here on the frozen Lake Bras d'Or.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend making a trip out to Martinique Beach.  It is about an hour and fifteen minutes away from Halifax.  Giant beautiful beach.  But be warned it is usually about 10 degrees colder than in Halifax.  Bring your sweatshirt!

- [Nova Scotia Tourism Link](http://www.novascotia.com/en/home/thingstoseeanddo/listingdetails.aspx/martinique-beach-provincial-park/1745)
- [Google Maps picture](http://www.google.ca/maps?q=Martinique%20beach,%20nova%20scotia&hl=en&ll=44.691402,-63.135836&spn=0.010236,0.016823&sll=49.891235,-97.15369&sspn=37.958411,68.90625&hq=Martinique%20beach,&hnear=Nova%20Scotia&t=m&z=16&layer=c&cbll=44.691402,-63.135836&cbp=12,0,,0,0&photoid=po-15317242)

Depending on the season it is also possible to rent surfboards and wetsuits.  Check out the [Happy Dudes surf shop](http://www.happydudes.ca/).

Answer (score 1):

When we last visited Nova Scotia, I made sure to take a quick trip to Peggy's Cove Lighthouse, toured the lighthouse and toured the memorial built to honor the SwissAir jetliner with 228 people aboard that crashed off Nova Scotia in [September 1998](http://www.cbc.ca/archives/categories/science-technology/transportation/swissair-111-joined-to-the-sea-and-the-sky/swissair-111-crashes-off-of-nova-scotia.html). Morbid, maybe, but I had never been in the vicinity of a tragedy like this before.

Comment: Peggy's Cove is worth visiting on its own account - lovely old lighthouse, cool rocks, wild waves (but don't get too close.)

Answer (score 0):

**Two more recommendations:**

- Visit Digby and have Scallops.
- Rent a car and drive around the Cabot Trail.